# Openam Approve Access Right Requests

Tags: authorization, openam

Do we have something out of the box in OpenAM like the following: Assume you have UserA, he wants to access page A, makes a request for that, some admin users approves the request, before finally system admin gives access to the user. And user is able to access the page after the system admin operation. Is that possible? Or do we need to build something custom for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom extension for this